# How can I make a nav scrolling horizontally with buttons when media queries kick in? html css, javascript and boostrap 5.2

Tags: javascript, html, sass, scroll, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a nav scrollable but horizontally and with buttons when media queries kicks in. I can't find any solution and it's becoming overwhelming. My team used bootstrap 5.2 and then used scss for styling the project. I think it was the worst mistake we did. We have to replicate EA site and it is starting to look pretty complicated.

I am trying to replicate the same behavior of the "lastest updates" nav when resized.
If you scroll down to "latest updates" in this link you can see it: https://www.ea.com/

What I've tried so far:

my HTML with script at the end of the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="container">
      <div class="scroll-horizontal">
        <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-left" onclick="scrollHorizontally(1)">I</button>
        <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-right" onclick="scrollHorizontally(-1)">I</button>
      </div>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <button
          class="nav-link h6 active"
          id="nav-notizie-ea-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-notizie-ea"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-notizie-ea"
          aria-selected="true"
        >
          <p>Notizie EA</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-ea-play-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-ea-play"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-ea-play"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>EA Play</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-fifa-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-fifa"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-fifa"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>FIFA</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-f1-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-f1"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-f1"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>F1</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-apex-legends-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-apex-legends"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-apex-legends"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>Apex Legends</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-the-sims-4-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-the-sims-4"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-the-sims-4"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>The Sims <sup>tm</sup>4</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-battlefield-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-battlefield"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-battlefield"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>Battlefield</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
        <button
          class="nav-link h6"
          id="nav-inside-ea-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          data-bs-target="#nav-inside-ea"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="nav-inside-ea"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          <p>Inside EA</p>
          <hr class="button-hr" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <hr class="nav-hr" />
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="nav-notizie-ea"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-notizie-ea-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-ea-play"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-ea-play-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-fifa"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-fifa-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-f1"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-f1-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-apex-legends"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-apex-legends-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-the-sims-4"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-the-sims-4-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-battlefield"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-battlefield-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="nav-inside-ea"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="nav-inside-ea-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      let currentScrollPosition = 0;
      let scrollAmount = 50;

      const navCont = document.querySelector(".nav");
      const horizontalScroll = document.querySelector(".scroll-horizontal");
      const btnScrollLeft = document.querySelector("#btn-scroll-left");
      const btnScrollRight = document.querySelector("#btn-scroll-right");

      let maxScroll= -navCont.offsetWidth + horizontalScroll.offsetWidth;

      function scrollHorizontally(val){
        currentScrollPosition += (val * scrollAmount); 
        
        if(currentScrollPosition > 0){
           currentScrollPosition = 0;
        }

        // if(currentScrollPosition < maxScroll){
        //    currentScrollPosition = maxScroll;
        // }
        
        navCont.style.left = currentScrollPosition + "px";          
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My SCSS:

```
@import "../abstracts/colors";

  .scroll-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 0px solid var(--gray);
    flex-shrink: 0;
    // overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.1s all ease-out;

    #nav-tab {

      position: relative;
    }

    .nav-link {
      height: 3.5rem;
      position: relative;
      color: black;
      border-radius: 0%;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      border: 0px;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      transition: 1s all ease-out;

      .button-hr {
        border: 0px;
        width: 85%;
        height: 2px;
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: var(--orange);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -27%;
        left: 7%;
        visibility: hidden;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      p {
        width: 100%;
        padding-inline: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        border-left: 1px solid var(--gray-focus);
        border-right: 1px solid var(--gray-focus);
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(1) p {
        border-left: none;
      }

      &:last-of-type p {
        border-right: none;
      }

      &:hover {
        background-color: transparentize(($gray-focus), 0.5);
      }
    }
    .nav-link.active {
      color: black, 0.5;
      background-color: transparentize(($gray-focus), 0.5);
      border-radius: 0%;
      .button-hr {
        visibility: visible;
        animation: myanimation 0.1s;
      }
    }
  }

  .nav-hr {
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid var(--gray-focus);
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }

  @keyframes myanimation {
    from {
      width: 1%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    to {
      width: 85%;
      left: 7%;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:808px) {
    .scroll-horizontal {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      z-index: 1;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: I think it is better to change the title of question. what you want is actually a slider or carousel. But you said **horizontal scrolling** in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to need a horizontal scroll javascript plugin.
Focus on getting the slider working first and then worry about hiding the arrows on desktop using media queries.

I can't really recommend a plugin but something lightweight like this? https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/

or something more feature rich like this?
https://swiperjs.com/demos

Answer (score 0):

I wrote totally new codes. I used [swiper slider](https://swiperjs.com/) to slide nav links at **for example** `md` resolution. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper-bootstrap-nav</title>
  <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
  />

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
  />

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper, .navbar {
      width: 90%;
      height: 80px;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #D35;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      width: 18%;
    }

    .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
      color: #055025;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-md-block d-none mt-5">
        <nav class="navbar mx-auto bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-1</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-2</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-3</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-4</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-5</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-6</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-7</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-8</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">link-9</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- slider nav is shown at "md" and below resolutions -->
      <div class="d-md-none mt-5">
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-1</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-2</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-3</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-4</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-5</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-6</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-7</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-8</button>

            <button class="swiper-slide btn btn-primary">link-9</button>

          </div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    spaceBetween: 20,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  });
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can test it at `md` resolution by changing the window width in your development environment. That is for solving the main problem of the question (nav sliding horizontally with buttons when media queries kick in). You must **link** the related content to each button. Also you may need to change styles according to your design.

Comment: I'm happy that my codes helped you!